# Serving static html in Google app engine Python

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, yaml

I'm having trouble getting static `.html` pages loaded for my Python
app. When I click on a link like *index.html*, I get a blank page and on the server log a 404 error. This is the same for other static `.html` files such as *about.html*.

The application works bar the static files. I've tried looking in
numerous places, but I cannot seem to get the .html pages up. i.e.

> INFO     2011-04-16 17:26:33,655 dev_appserver.py:3317] "GET /
>   terms.html HTTP/1.1" 404 -

**yaml:**

```
application: quote
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /index\.html
script: index.py

- url: /
script: index.py

- url: /(.*\.(html))
static_files: static/\1
upload: static/HTML/(.*\.(html))


- url: /favicon.ico
static_files: static/images/favicon.ico
upload: images/favicon.ico
mime_type: image/x-icon

- url: /css
static_dir: static/css

- url: /images
static_dir: static/images

- url: /js
static_dir: static/js
```

My static files are located in static/HTML and *index.html* is in the main folder.

I have also tried this, but it seems to make no difference at all:

```
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: static/images/favicon.ico
  upload: images/favicon.ico
  mime_type: image/x-icon

- url: /css
  static_dir: static/css

- url: /images
  static_dir: static/images

 - url: /js
  static_dir: static/js

 - url: /(.*\.(html))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/HTML/(.*\.(html))

 - url: /index\.html
  script: index.py

 - url: /
 script: index.py
```

Comment: OK, Tha doesnnks, I have the static stuff done. Now I have the additional problem of adding another script handler that does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep your HandlerScripts below the Static Directory handling portion. IOW, just move this to the last.

```
- url: /index\.html
script: index.py

- url: /
script: index.py
```

Comment: Thanks, but this makes no difference. Here is what I have:

Comment: - url: /favicon.ico

  static_files: static/images/favicon.ico

  upload: images/favicon.ico

  mime_type: image/x-icon



- url: /css

  static_dir: static/css



- url: /images

  static_dir: static/images



- url: /js

  static_dir: static/js



- url: /(.*\.(html))

  static_files: static/\1

  upload: static/HTML/(.*\.(html))






- url: /index\.html

  script: index.py


- url: /

  script: index.py

Comment: Ordering does not matter here - handlers are matched in the order they're listed, and none of the handlers match any of the others.

Comment: @Nick - I was wondering if his Dynamic handler was masking the path to static ones (quite a common prb). I read below that the path to static required correction.

Comment: @SenthilKumaran +1 this has been killing me for hours. Thanks.

Comment: I need to add about.html --- it gives me this error: The url "/about.html" does not match any handlers.

Comment: @RamyHassan, follow the above logic and instead of index\.html, use about\.html

Answer (score 2):

Put an `/HTML` in your static_files path:

```
- url: /(.*\.(html))
  static_files: static/HTML/\1
  upload: static/HTML/(.*\.(html))
```

Comment: @Dave You also have a handler defined to match `/index.html` with the Python script `index.py` - so that URL will be served by a dynamic handler, even if you have a file `static/HTML/index.html`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to define each directory seperatly in you yaml file

```
handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: my_application/static
```

Then in your relevant html file that you will render with django you can call your static content for example like

```
<script src="/static/less_lib.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you static folder for this example should be under the root folder of your app.

Comment: yes I could do this, but this I doubt would solve the issue at hand. Plus I'm fairly minimal, and there is no need to use the extra /static in the html in my case. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

You must properly indent your YAML.

**Provided**

script at incorrect level

```
handlers:
- url: /index\.html
script: index.py
```

json equivalent

```
{
  "handlers": [
    {
      "url": "/index\\.html"
    }
  ], 
  "script": "index.py"
}
```

**Indented**

script at correct level

```
handlers:
- url: /index\.html
  script: index.py
```

json equivalent

```
{
  "handlers": [
    {
      "url": "/index\\.html", 
      "script": "index.py"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Online YAML Parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/)

Comment: all are be indented correctly in the file. its on here that the format is warped.

Comment: @dave, I guess I need to try harder now.