# How to load .html page with Python on App Engine

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, webapp2

In the following example, the `.html` data is in the same file as the Python code (as variable `MAIN_PAGE_HTML`).

I want the `.html` content in its own different file.

How do I present the HTML page? Must I always use `Jinja2` to load it?

Or is there a simpler way to get the content of my `.html` and pass it to `self.response.write`?

```
import cgi from google.appengine.api import users import webapp2

MAIN_PAGE_HTML = """\ <html>   <body>
    <form action="/sign" method="post">
      <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
      <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
    </form>   </body> </html> """

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write(MAIN_PAGE_HTML)

class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        self.response.write('<html><body>You wrote:<pre>')
        self.response.write(cgi.escape(self.request.get('content')))
        self.response.write('</pre></body></html>')

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/sign', Guestbook), ], debug=True)
```

My `.html` file contains a form that user can fill and send to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) it's a template engine, basically merge variables before to be served in the client, but [webapp2](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/gettingstarted/templates.html) include the template engine by itself

```
import webapp2
import os #added
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template #also added

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates/index.html') 
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, {}))        

class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self): #didn't change this
        self.response.write('<html><body>You wrote:<pre>')
        self.response.write(cgi.escape(self.request.get('content')))
        self.response.write('</pre></body></html>')

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/sign', Guestbook), ], debug=True)
```

So basically you can use webapp2, jinja or [others](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates) templates engines, but out of the box app engine only offers webapp2 (django) and jinja2

To serve static files (images, js, css, etc.) and in the handlers section in you app.yaml file

```
handlers:
- url: /images # in the html can access from localhost:8080/images
  static_dir: templates/images # folder template, subfolder images
- url: /js
  static_dir: templates/js  
- url: /css
  static_dir: templates/css  
- url: /fonts
  static_dir: templates/fonts  
- url: /assets
  static_dir: templates/assets
```

according to this yaml file, this would be the structure in your project

```
-  MyAppFolder
-- Templates
---- images
---- js
---- css
---- fonts
---- assets
```

Answer (score 3):

[jinja2](/questions/tagged/jinja2) gives you a decent and simple way to serve dynamic content to your users: I would recommend this [approach](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates) if you need dynamic content.

Alternatively, if you only need static content, then use [static pages](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/staticfiles).
(Note that StackOverflow has posts on how to do this: e.g.: [Serving static html in Google app engine Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693976/serving-static-html-in-google-app-engine-python))

You may also load your own files dynamically if desired, but I do not think that this is the preferred route for your problem.

Comment: sorry if I am having trouble with this. So you are saying I should be able to load my home screen without using `class Guestbook(webapp2.RequestHandler):` and if that is correct, is that a good practice? Thanks.

Comment: Yes - your home page (the Mainpage GET in this case) can be statically served which then requests a dynamic URL (in your case the 'sign' POST call). The URLs would need to be distinguishable in the app.yaml though. I am unsure what is regarded as 'best practice' however.